# App launch image not updating

Tags: ios, xcode

I changed the image used in my launch screen, but for some reason the old one still shows when I launch the app. I've deleted DerivedData, cleaned the app, deleted the app from my iPhone, open/closed Xcode, not sure what I should do? In the storyboard it even shows the new image.

Comment: Check you have change all image on lauch image

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the Springboard cache. 
- Uninstall the app after an update
- Reboot the device
- Install the updated version.

This should have cleared the Springboards cache.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method to update launch image 
On simulator: Reset simulator (Hardware -> Erase all content and settings)
On Devices  : Edit scheme -> Run -> change build configuration 'Debug' to 'Release' then run on simulator or devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your launch image in images.xcassets instead of storyboard?

Comment: didn't think it made a difference. Shouldn't it work either way?